# Necesito ejecutar un script de SQL Server en CMD

Tags: sql-server

Este Script ya lo ejecute sin ningún problema en PowerShell, este me ejecuta toda la carpeta de la ruta la cual contiene varios SP. Quiero hacer este mismo proceso en una computadora que tiene windows 7 a travez de CMD, ya que esta no tiene el powershell.
/*Script*/

```
 foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem -path “E:\Merge SQL\ - cAST\Merge -
 Alter\” -Filter *.sql) { 
    sqlcmd -S COFUBALDEW10P  -U sa -P linKmobiL1 -d RWLocal -i $f.fullname 
}
```

Comment: Puesto que ya estás utilizando sqlcmd que es la utilidad para ejecutar scripts SQL desde cmd, creo que lo que necesitas es ayuda en generar algo que recorra todos los archivos.

Comment: Espero que esa no sea una contraseña real.

Comment: 1. ¿Me puedes ayudar con el script que recorra todos los archivos por favor?
2. Obvio que no es una contraseña real. xD

Answer (score 1):

Sólo necesitarías utilizar los comandos básicos que existían antes de Powershell.

```
for /r "E:\Merge SQL\ - cAST\Merge - Alter\" %i in (*.sql) do sqlcmd -S COFUBALDEW10P -U sa -P linKmobiL1 -d RWLocal -i "%i"
```

Puedes leer un poco más acerca del `for` [aquí](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html).